# Как получать первые буквы Фамиилии Имени и Отчества?

Tags: php

Всем привет, нужна такая помощь, есть допустим такое Ф.И.О - Иванов Алексей Сергеевич, нужно вывести лишь - ИАС. Как такое можно реализовать? 
Нашёл такую функцию:

```
$string = "Progress in Veterinary Science";

$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[a-z]/i';
preg_match_all($expr, $string, $matches);

$result = implode('', $matches[0]);

$result = strtoupper($result);

echo $result;
```

но она работает только для латинских букв, как можно сделать такое для кириллицы?

Comment: добавить помимо `i` еще и `u` в конце?

Comment: Я бы по пробелам разбил и вытащил бы первый символ

Comment: кириллица 2 байта занимает на символ

Comment: вспомнилось что-то https://habr.com/ru/post/146901/

Comment: @teran, не понял юмора)

Answer (score 3):

> *как можно сделать такое для кириллицы?*

Обычно достаточно добавления модификатора `u`. Но кроме этого ваш код можно сократить буквально до двух строк:

```
$text = 'Иванов Алексей Сергеевич';

echo preg_replace('~(\pL)\S+|\s+~u', '$1', $text);
```

Comment: Поясните регулярку.

Comment: @doox911 захват первой буквы, за которой следует любое количество непробельных символов, или пробел _(поиск пробела нужен для его же удаления)_.

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = "Progress in Veterinary Science";
$arr = explode(" ", $string);

echo mb_strtoupper($arr[0][0].$arr[1][0].$arr[2][0]);
```

Функция [mb_strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strtoupper.php) переводит символ в верхний регистр.

Answer (score -1):

Вместо `a-z` пишем `а-я`, а к регулярке добавляем `u` для поддержки юникода

```
$string = "Привет Тест";

$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[а-я]/ui';
preg_match_all($expr, $string, $matches);

$result = implode('', $matches[0]);

$result = strtoupper($result);

echo $result;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a967e1fed67e9af98461aa7a9ae6fc31420f9593

Answer (score -1):

```
$str='Иванов Сергей Петрович';
$str=explode(' ',$str);
$chery=count($str);
for($i = 0; $i <= $chery-1; $i++) {
$arr=preg_split('//u', $str[$i], null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$du[]=$arr[0];
}
print_r($du);
```